# Enemy chasing player 2D array in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

So guys I'm creating a game and in a specific fase I've got an enemy and a player who spawns randomly on a 10x10 array and then the enemy must move towards the player until they are on adjacent cells. The player is controled by the user and the enemy must move in his direction to catch him.
I already started and did the array margin checks and where the enemy can move but I don't have any idea how to do the chase thing. Can you help me?

```
public void enemyMovement()
{
    if(enemyAlive) {
        if( enemy.getCurrentLine() == 0 ) {
            if( enemy.getCurrentColumn() == 0 ) {
                // only moves to right and down
            }
            else if( enemy.getCurrentColumn() == 9 ) {
                // only moves to left and down
            }
            else {
                // moves to the sides or down
            }
        }
        else if( enemy.getCurrentLine() == 9 ) {
            if( enemy.getCurrentColumn() == 0 ) {
                // only moves up or right
            }
            else if( enemy.getCurrentColumn() == 9 ) {
                // only moves up or left
            }
            else {
                // only moves to the sides and up
            }
        }
        else if ( enemy.getCurrentColumn() == 0 ) {
            if( enemy.getCurrentLine()  != 0 &&  enemy.getCurrentLine()  != 9) {
                // can go anywhere excepts left
            }
        }
        else if( enemy.getCurrentColumn() == 9 ) {
            if( enemy.getCurrentLine()  != 0 &&  enemy.getCurrentLine()  != 9) {
                // can go anywhere excepts right
            }
        }
        else {
            // can goes anywhere
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not a coding service and your question implies to solve the problem for you. I can give you a tipp: When you know the position of the user and the position of the enemy in a 2-dimensional space, it should be rather easy to find out where the enemy has to go if you look at each dimension seperately.

Answer (score 1):

Check the distance between the enemy and the player, and move along with the axis which the distance is longer. For example, if the coordinate of the enemy is (1,2) and the player is at (9,5), then the distance between them is (8,3), so the enemy should move along x axis to (2,2). If the distance between them is something like (5,5), then you can choose x/y axis priority or just randomly choose one axis.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I think I can solve the problem